# how to generate pdf Table with dynamic number of column with spring mvc

Tags: pdf-generation, itext, dynamicpdf-table2

I am trying to generate PDF and download it. is there any way to make a service to add a column in pdf Tabel?. Can we give dynamic number of columns in pdfTable?

Comment: What have you tried? In iText 5, you can create a `PdfPTable` with any number of columns; in iText 7, you can create a `Table` with any kind of number. Either you haven't written any code yet (and therefor you haven't discovered how trivial your question is), or I don't understand the question. Did you read [this chapter on tables](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-5-adding-abstractelement-objects-part-2)?

Comment: I wrote the code but i want to know if it is possible to give create pdf with dynamic column. Thank you for that link.